# Error importing geoloaction package in pubspec.yaml

Tags: intellij-idea, dart, flutter

How can i resolve the errror while importing geoloaction package in pubspec.yaml ??
The current Dart SDK version is 2.1.0-dev.5.0.flutter-a2eb050044.

Because untitled67 depends on geolocation any which requires SDK version <2.0.0, version solving failed.

Answer (score 1):

https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/geolocation shows a red badge telling you that it is not compatible with Dart 2.

Recent Flutter versions depend on Dart 2

See also https://github.com/loup-v/geolocation/issues/44

especially https://github.com/loup-v/geolocation/issues/44#issuecomment-431572295

> ```
> geolocation:
>   git:
>     url: 'https://github.com/shehabic/geolocation'
> ```